# Bootstrap: Z-index makes element not clickable. Looking for a way to put every element behind another

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, accordion, z-index, bootstrap-accordion

I have a problem with my accordion - only first item opens. Reason is not the `data-target`.

When I run my code without CSS it works...I tried removing lines from the css to see where the problem is and I found that the problem is with the Z-INDEX.

Because I position every collapsible element behind the last one, it makes them un-clickable. The reason I want each element behind another is because the bottom border pd each card is round, so I need each element to hide the top of the one after it:

https://jsfiddle.net/81co7502/

```
    <section class="mobileSection">
    <section id="aboutMobile">
        <header class="hamNav">
            <div class="container-fluid accordionRow">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 colsAccordion">
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                            <div class="card" id="historyCard">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            היסטוריה
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>

                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                                        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" id="whoWeAreCard">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                            מי אנחנו?
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                                        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" id="numbersCard">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                            "בשבילי" במספרים"
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                                        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" id="sayingCard">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                            צעירים אומרים...
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                                        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card" id="contactCard">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                            צור קשר
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                                        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                                        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>
```

(in the fiddle, the cards seem rectangular but in my code they have rounded borders at the bottom).

```
        .hamNav {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #headingOne {

    }



    .card{
        border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
        border:none;
    }

    #historyCard {
        background-color: #ffb59b;
        margin-top:-50px;
        padding-top:60px;
    }

    #whoWeAreCard {
        background-color: #ffe285;
        margin-top: -80px;
        padding-top: 70px;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    #numbersCard {
        background-color: #9abada;
        margin-top: -90px;
        padding-top: 80px;
        z-index: -2;
    }

    #sayingCard {
        background-color: #8adffa;
        margin-top: -100px;
        padding-top: 90px;
        z-index: -3;
    }

    #contactCard {
        background-color: #ffcd9b;
        margin-top: -110px;
        padding-top: 100px;
        z-index: -4;
    }

    .card-header {
        border: none;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 110px;
    }

    h5 {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:25px;

    }
```

is there a way of achieving what I need (an element to hide the top of the element that follows) without using z-index?

Comment: any feedback on the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using `padding` minus `margin` value to get around the issue of putting the divs one behind the other... Check the code below which places the div using `:nth-child(99)` so that we don't need to use IDs (you can use that for colors also).

```css
.card{ text-align: center; border-bottom-left-radius:25% !important;
border-bottom-right-radius:25% !important;
border:none !important; }
.card-header{padding: 30px; }
.accordion{ padding: 25px 0;}        

#historyCard { background-color: #ffb59b;  }
#whoWeAreCard { background-color: #ffe285;  }
#numbersCard { background-color: #9abada;  }
#sayingCard { background-color: #8adffa;   }
#contactCard { background-color: #ffcd9b;   }

.card:nth-child(1){top: -25px;}
.card:nth-child(2){top: -25px;}
.card:nth-child(3){top: -25px;}
.card:nth-child(4){top: -25px;}
.card:nth-child(5){top: -25px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="mobileSection">
  <section id="aboutMobile">
    <header class="hamNav">
      <div class="container-fluid accordionRow">
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 colsAccordion">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
              <div class="card" id="historyCard">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                היסטוריה
                                            </button>
                  </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                    on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                    raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" id="whoWeAreCard">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                                מי אנחנו?
                                            </button>
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                    on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                    raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" id="numbersCard">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                "בשבילי" במספרים"
                                            </button>
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                    on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                    raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" id="sayingCard">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                צעירים אומרים...
                                            </button>
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                    on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                    raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card" id="contactCard">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                צור קשר
                                            </button>
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                    on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                    raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>
```